# Google trend widget into a Geckoboard

Tags: javascript, dashboard, google-trends, geckoboard

I am looking to integrate a google trend widget into a Geckoboard dashboard. I know that Geckoboard integrates other google products such as GA or Adwords, but I haven't seen Google trends here. Although, Google trends provides some java script to plug a google trends graph into a HTLM page, can it be used in Geckoboard? I have been looking here
https://developer.geckoboard.com/json#introduction, but couldn't find out if it was possible or not.

I must confess I don't know how to code, but I am looking to know if it's (easily) feasible or not for someone who does know and what the main main steps would be for that.

I believe it can be useful to any web marketing team who want to track clout of his brand compare to competitor. Thx in advance!